# UPDATED: Setting arguments when a Class method is called in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made this simple program to emulate a radio station. I need to figure out how to set presets based on what the current station is.

Here are the menu options:

```
print("\n1 = Display tuned in station")
print("2 = Program preset station 1")
print("3 = Program preset station 2")
print("4 = Program preset station 3")
print("5 = Seek next station")
print("6 = Tune preset station 1")
print("7 = Tune preset station 2")
print("8 = Tune preset station 3")
print("9 = Dump Programming")
print("10 = Turn off radio")
```

When you select "5" the radio seeks to the next station. This is done is the CLASS METHOD [def seekNext(self):]

So what I need help with, how do you set the current station to a preset when selecting options "2, 3, and 4" using the CLASS METHOD [def longPressPreset1through3(self):]?

Also after setting the presets, how can I use the CLASS METHOD [def shortPressPreset1through3(self):] to display what the presets are?

```
class Radio:

def __init__(self):
    self.stations=["STATIC","97.2", "99.6", "101.7", "105.3", "108.5"]
    self.station_index = 0
    self.current = self.stations[0]
    self.preset = 0
    self.presetStation1 = self.stations[0]
    self.presetStation2 = self.stations[0]
    self.presetStation3 = self.stations[0]

def seekNext(self):
    self.stations[self.station_index]
    self.station_index = (self.station_index + 1) % len(self.stations)
    self.current = self.stations[self.station_index]
    return self.current

def longPressPreset1through3(self):
    pass

def shortPressPreset1through3(self):
    pass
```

Comment: what is the significance of the line `self.stations[self.station_index]
` it seems to have no effect. Also what does `displayMenuGetOption()` return?

Comment: I can't run this code can you please share some samples on how to use it? Raises all sorts of exceptions

Comment: The assignment `presetStation1 = self.stations[0]` in `__init__` should start with `self.`. Without that the assigned name is local to the function, and can not be accessed later by the methods. I would also suggest using single a list rather than three variables.

Comment: I updated the post to clarify what I was asking.

Comment: Would you describe what are you trying to do algorithmically, step by step? Your description is unclear. And im sure you can easily learn by completing a pair of tutorials at sites like codeschool.com Putting your presets in a separate object (a class or a list / dict etc) would probably help you also

Answer (score 0):

This is how you define and acess the instance and calss attributes:

```
class YourClass:
    another_preset = 0 # the class attributes are defined here, and accessed the same way as instance attributes (plus can be accessed in the class itself like this: ‘YourClass.another_preset’),  but are shared among all instances
    def __init__(self):
        self.preset = 0  # instance variable - will be unique for every instance

    def set_preset_to(self, x):
        self.preset = x  # this is how you access the instance or class attributes inside a method

    def do_something_with_preset(self):
        self.preset += 2 # they can also be modified
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I wasn't able to use it to get the results I needed.

Comment: @NickNasty, I will be happy to help if you desribe more detailed what your buttonPrrss methods should do :) im going to bed, but will answer tomorrow, if anyone else wont help u

Comment: Thanks Bob. It's okay. I'm about to see the solution in class tonight. I think a list would work though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead on declaring them on `__init__`, you can also add them without `__init__`

```
class Radio:
    stations=["STATIC","97.2", "99.6", "101.7", "105.3", "108.5"]
    station_index = 0
    current = self.stations[0]
    presetStation1 = stations[0]
    presetStation2 = stations[0]
    presetStation3 = stations[0]
```

I don't think this is the most elegant solution nor good practice though, since the presetStations might change during the program, but it fits your requirements.